# How to insert commas into text fields

Tags: php, mysql

```
<? echo $rows['general']; ?><? echo $rows['comment']; ?>
```

'general' is a text field but 'comment' is a checkmark item. It works fine if I type in the text field or if I select the checkmark; but if I fill the text form and also check the checkmark then I would like them to be separated with a comma and space.

Comment: You could use javascript to make see if both the text field and the comment checkbox have been populated, then insert a comma inbetween (if thats what you are asking about)

Comment: This seems like a fragment from half way through a question and makes no sense on its own. Please expand, a lot. Please also turn off [`short_open_tag`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) and stop using them as you are writing low portability code.

Comment: What do you want separated by a comma and a space?  The contents of the text form and the name of the checkbox?  Are wanting them to be comma separated on the server side?

Comment: You should be using `<?php` instead of the lazier `<?`... better coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if thous are the only 2 field:

```
echo implode(',', array_filter($rows));
```

otherwise you can use trim to remove the , if not needed:

```
echo trim("{$rows['general']},{$rows['comment']}", ', ');
```

Comment: Your second snippet is cryptic (to me, at least).

Comment: i concat both text whit an , between them, if one of the text is empty the , is going to end up at one of the ends, and then i tell trim to remove , from the ends

Answer (score 2):

```
$separation = "";
if(!empty($rows['general']) && !empty($rows['comment'])) {
     $separation = ", ";
}

echo $rows['general'] . $separation . $rows['comment'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
if (($rows['general'] != "") && ($rows['comment'] != "")) {
    echo $rows['general'] + ", "+ $rows['comment'];
} else {
    echo $rows['general'] + $rows['comment'];
}
```